# How to combine filename and extension in windows batch file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, command

I have managed to extract the filename and the extension and passed that to a `.bat` file in windows. It's like

```
%1 = filename
%2 = extension
```

The problem that I am having is that I can't seem to do `%1%2` because the command doesnt seem to like the `%1%2` command ? If I do `%1<space>%2` it seems happy but then the file is broken because its like `file<space>.js`

How am I able to get them side by side and still print out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@set NAME=somefile
@set SUFFIX=txt
@echo file = %NAME%.%SUFFIX%
```

OUTPUT:

> file = somefile.txt

Comment: thanks but the suffix in my case is actually `.js` so using this it would be `file..js` ?

Comment: But using this would be exactly what you're looking for: `%NAME%%SUFFIX%` ;)  Try my script (with ".txt", and without ".") and see